# SQL Server Query Store's Total Duration Value Seems High

Tags: sql-server, sql-query-store

I've been looking at SQL Server's Query Store, specifically at the overall resource consumption view. It has a "total duration" field. I put a 60 minute workload on the server and this field is reporting 25 hours of duration. Is this being tracked by thread? Is that why it is reporting so high?

Comment: See posted answer

Answer (score 0):

I traced the query that is sent when you refresh the grid in the query store. It expressed total duration like this:

ROUND(CONVERT(float, SUM(rs.avg_duration*rs.count_executions))*0.001,2) as total_duration,

So, we can say that the total duration is the total duration in terms of milliseconds for all queries run during the configured time frame within the query store.

Comment: Please help me understand this; Total Duration is calculated for all queries during the configured time frame and summed up for overall resource consumption view. Is this correct?